# Socialdemocratico o socialista o cosa?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-choice, vocabulary, nouns

Come si definisce una persona o un partito che sostiene il cosiddetto stato sociale (welfare state)? Socialista, socialdemocratico o come?

Comment: Credo che in Italia quasi tutti i partiti, da destra a sinistra, supportino almeno a parole il cosiddetto "stato sociale". Purtroppo I nomi dei partiti sono parte della propaganda politica e non della grammatica.

Comment: Visto che socialdemocrazia, socialismo democratico, socialismo e via dicendo sono tutte sfumature dello stesso colore non credo che "sostenere lo stato sociale" sia una definizione che basti a distinguerle tra di loro.

Comment: Non saprei la domanda me la sono posta perché di colore completamente opposto il Nazionalsocialismo e il Movimento sociale usano lo stesso il termine. Tuttavia se si parla di Socialismo si cade sempre dall'altra parte dello schieramento politico

Comment: Il “colore politico” da una parte e la maggiore o minor spinta verso la socializzazione di beni e servizi sono, per così dire, assi diversi su cui si pone la posizione politica di una persona o di un partito. Vedi per esempio la descrizione in termini di “[political compass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_compass)” (che a sua volta è discutibile). Comunque non mi sembra una domanda di lingua italiana, ma di definizioni di orientamenti politici.

Comment: @DaG esiste uno stack exchange per questo? Non ho trovato dove altro chiederlo, specialmente in lingua italiana

Comment: @FrancescoCerofolini Esiste http://politics.stackexchange.com/, anche se il focus è decisamente non sulla politica italiana

Comment: @Francesco Se per Movimento Sociale intendi il vecchio MSI di Almirante è molto sbagliato dire che era di colore completamente opposto al Naziolalsocialismo. Il MSI era il partito più di destra di tutti

Comment: @SantiBailors intendo quello ma non intendevo di colore opposto, anzi era per fare due esempi totalmente opposti al concerto di Socialismo di sinistra che tuttavia mantengono la parola "sociale" nel nome

Comment: Ah, capito! Allora hai ragione, avevo inteso "opposto fra di loro".

Comment: Suggerisco *populista* :)

Comment: Avere la parola sociale nel nome significa pochino, alcune dottrine hanno origine da ideologie della parte opposta. Anche il fascismo nella sua storia non e' sempre stato a destra. Nazionalsocialismo e' socialismo radicale di stampo nazionalista e più robaccia ci attacchi più lo spingi all'altro estremo. Nella tua domanda non menzioni quello che hai spiegato nel commento cmq. Forse questo come inizio https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spettro_politico

Comment: I termini che citi denominano ideologie politiche, non specifiche preferenze per questo o quell'istituto politico/sociale, così come non ci sono parole per indicare chi è a favore, o contro, la pena di morte, la caccia, i matrimoni gay, la scuola pubblica statale, ecc., ecc..